# Who was the third guy that was affected by Loki's sceptre at the start of the Avengers movie?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, the-avengers-2012

Nick Fury says at one point "He (Loki) has already converted two of my best men" but in the beginning of the movie it clearly shows Loki converted a third guy. 
Who was that guy?

The fact he was present in the room indicates (to me at least) he had to be a pretty high ranking security officer, but he's never named at all. Yet he does support/guide Loki when they run from the room when the Tesseract goes ballistic. And the fact he survived that (touching Loki) also must mean he's pretty important. 
I'm guessing security again, figuring he'd be in charge of safeguarding the base while Hawkeye is after the stuff for Selvig. But that is just speculation.

Was he just taking up screen time so it showed Loki busy with converting while Nick attempts to get away with the Tesseract?

Comment: Obviously not one of Nick Fury's best men.

Comment: His name is "Peggy" Loki recruited him from a call center in Kazakhstan.

Comment: The classic [red shirt](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RedShirt).

Comment: @Xantec what do you base that on?

Comment: @silvith I base it on standard operating procedure in Hollywood productions, however, it was merely meant as a joke.

Comment: Was Nick Fury counting the scientist from Thor as one of his best men? Because if it was two top agents and the scientist, the count makes sense.

Comment: @Xantec ah sorry, I thought you were serious ...

Comment: @rsegal I think he was indeed referring to Selvig as one of his best, afaik Selvig was enlisted/employed by SHIELD to work on the Tesseract

Comment: I have to agree with Xantec on this one however. I think it was shown loki turning him as lets face it loki is powerful and all but he needed a few high ranking security personnel to get out of their without too much trouble as if he had got stuck under the cave-in he may well have not survived. I think that other guy was just there to be turned to help Loki escape. @Chad this is cannot be the same person the question refers too as the guy was at the beginning in the research centre. You also see 2 people get killed by Loki who are just wearing normal shield uniform showing that they might not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He was a security officer.

Loki probably had several reasons for turning him (3 that I can think of):

1. Help in getting ou of the underground base without a fight or attracting unwanted attention.
2. Help for Dr. Selvig & the other "recruits" working on the portal device (this makes more sense when you take into account that Loki planned on being captured and so would have to leave the task of building the device and stealing it's components up to people he'd turned).
3. Turned people apparently retained all their knowledge, so he would have been an invaluable intelligence resource to help Loki with his plan.

Comment: I accepted this as answer because I suppose "a security officer" is indeed everything there is known about this character.